# EF Interitance and DBA Concerns

Tags: entity-framework, database-design, orm, entity-framework-4

For a new project, our application developers are wanting to use Entity Framework's table-per-type inheritance model.

We recently showed this functionality and the resulting table schema to our DBA, and he's expressed concerns, and I'm wondering how to address them. Inheritance is an important part of OO, and from a development side, it would be great to have the DB and ORM support this concept natively. This functionality is part of EF, so it's not like we're pulling the design out of left field.

His main concerns are:

- We're not using stored procs
- The added complexity will make reporting and data updates harder

We've pretty much addressed his stored proc concerns (and we've been using another ORM for 3 years now).

As far as the complexity, I do see his point, but the counterpoints address them (for me):

- Reporting should not be performed from transactional tables (we currently do this), views or a transformed reporting DB should be used.
- Data updates on a flatter structure can still mess up data -- it's the responsibility of the person updating the data to understand the structure. The schema used by EF's table-per-type inheritance model isn't that complex, but it must be adhered to when doing manual updates.

I know we're not the first to run into DBA concerns over DB-backed model inheritance. How have others convinced their DBA that this is a good model?

Comment: I should add that I wish there were a way to enforce the inheritance model with database-level constraints. It's great that EF will always make sure data is inserted/updated properly, but I don't like the fact that there's nothing at the DB level to ensure data integrity. That said, I'm not sure how that could be done without the use of inefficient, manually-coded triggers or something similar. Am I wrong?

Comment: Reporting against views still end up hitting transactional tables. You are correct, however, in asserting that reporting should be performed against a transformed reporting DB.

Comment: You're right. I should have said reporting against the transactional schema, not tables.

Answer (score 3):

His main concerns are not considering real problems with TPT.

- You can use stored procedures with TPT if you want.
- Data updates are not harder. EF will deal with them and ensure correct order of data modification.

The main problem of TPT are [inefficient queries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/08/17/performance-considerations-when-using-tpt-table-per-type-inheritance-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) (check comments as well). TPT in EF has real performance problems becuase it makes a lot of left joins and unions even if it doesn't need data from derived tables. Creating any reporting on this data structure and accessing report data through EF is really bad decision.

Edit:

If his concerns are related to other tools working with your database then they are fully legitimate but in the same time it is only about correct documentation of your database structure.

Comment: Maybe this wasn't clear, but I was referring to updates done SQL statements and reporting done through other tools like SSRS. EF doesn't come into play in either of his areas of concern.